# jsf - Dropdown not updating its selected value with the entity's - NPE in selected entity's getId()

Tags: jsf, drop-down-menu, primefaces, nullpointerexception

In the JSF page for updating some entity, a dropdown is used to select the desired row:

[image]

Then all fields are filled with the selected row information, except the dropdowns:

[image]

I created two methods, one for loading each dropdown, in the entity's managed bean. For the first one I used the following code:

```
public List<Rede> getRedes() {
    if (this.redes == null) {
        redes = redeBean.findWithNamedQuery("Rede.findAll");
    }
    if (this.estabelecimento.getId() > 0) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("estabelecimento_id", this.estabelecimento.getId());
        this.rede = (Rede) redeBean.findWithNamedQuery("Rede.findByEstabelecimentoId", map).get(0);
        for (Rede r : redes) {
            if(Objects.equals(this.rede.getId(), r.getId())) {
                this.rede = r;
            }
        }
    }
    return redes;
}
```

But `estabelecimento.getId()` throws `NullPointerException`, but `estabelecimento` is not null. Estabelecimento is instantiated in the `PostConstruct` method.

The alterar.xhtml page:

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.id}" />
        <f:viewParam name="redeId" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.rede.id}" />
        <f:viewParam name="categoriaId" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.categoria.id}" />
    </f:metadata>
    <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" globalOnly="true" />

        <p:panelGrid id="pnl" columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel for="estabelecimentos" value="Estabelecimento:" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="estabelecimentos" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.id}" >
                <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="-- Selecione --" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimentos}" var="x" itemValue="#{x.id}" itemLabel="#{x.nomefantasia}" />
                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{estabelecimentoMB.prepareEdit(estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.id)}" update="@form" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:message for="estabelecimentos" />
        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:separator />

        <p:panelGrid id="pnl-info" columns="3">
            <p:outputLabel for="cnpj" value="CNPJ:" />
            <p:inputText id="cnpj" required="true" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.cnpj}" />
            <p:message for="cnpj" />

            <p:outputLabel for="razaosocial" value="Razão Social:" />
            <p:inputText id="razaosocial" required="true" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.razaosocial}" />
            <p:message for="razaosocial" />

            <p:outputLabel for="nomefantasia" value="Nome Fantasia:" />
            <p:inputText id="nomefantasia" required="true" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.nomefantasia}" />
            <p:message for="nomefantasia" />

            <p:outputLabel for="cep" value="CEP:" />
            <p:inputText id="cep" required="true" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.cep}" />
            <p:message for="cep" />

            <p:outputLabel for="logradouro" value="Logradouro:" />
            <p:inputText id="logradouro" required="true" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.logradouro}" />
            <p:message for="logradouro" />

            <p:outputLabel for="numero" value="Número:" />
            <p:inputText id="numero" required="true" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.numero}" />
            <p:message for="numero" />

            <p:outputLabel for="razaosocial" value="Razão Social:" />
            <p:inputText id="complemento" required="true" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.razaosocial}" />
            <p:message for="razaosocial" />

            <p:outputLabel for="bairro" value="Bairro:" />
            <p:inputText id="bairro" required="true" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.bairro}" />
            <p:message for="bairro" />

            <p:outputLabel for="cidade" value="Cidade:" />
            <p:inputText id="cidade" required="true" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.cidade}" />
            <p:message for="cidade" />

            <p:outputLabel for="estado" value="Estado:" />
            <p:inputText id="estado" required="true" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.estado}" />
            <p:message for="estado" />

            <p:outputLabel for="pais" value="País:" />
            <p:inputText id="pais" required="true" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.pais}" />
            <p:message for="pais" />

            <p:outputLabel for="telefone" value="Telefone:" />
            <p:inputText id="telefone" required="true" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.telefone}" />
            <p:message for="telefone" />

            <p:outputLabel for="contato" value="Contato:" />
            <p:inputText id="contato" required="true" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.contato}" />
            <p:message for="contato" />

            <p:outputLabel for="email" value="E-mail:" />
            <p:inputText id="email" required="true" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.email}" />
            <p:message for="email" />

            <p:outputLabel for="site" value="Site:" />
            <p:inputText id="site" required="true" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.site}" />
            <p:message for="site" />

            <p:outputLabel for="latitude" value="Latitude:" />
            <p:inputText id="latitude" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.latitude}" />
            <p:message for="latitude" />

            <p:outputLabel for="longitude" value="Longitude:" />
            <p:inputText id="longitude" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.estabelecimento.longitude}" />
            <p:message for="longitude" />

            <p:outputLabel for="redes" value="Rede:" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="redes" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.rede.id}" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Selecione --" itemValue="0" />
                <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{rede.nomefantasia}" itemValue="#{rede.id}" value="#{redeMB.redes}" var="rede" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:message for="redes" />

            <p:outputLabel for="categorias" value="Categoria:" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="categorias" value="#{estabelecimentoMB.categoria.id}" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Selecione --" itemValue="0" />
                <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{categoria.nome}" itemValue="#{categoria.id}" value="#{categoriaEstabelecimentoMB.categorias}" var="categoria" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:message for="categorias" />

            <p:commandButton action="#{estabelecimentoMB.save}" value="Salvar" update="@form" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

The `prepareEdit` method has only this line: `this.estabelecimento = this.estabelecimentoBean.findById(id);`

`EstabelecimentoMB` is ViewScoped.

Comment: Please refrain from using a foreign language in your code. This is not so nice for anyone except those who happen to speak your particular language to read. Thanks ;)

Comment: Understood. Gonna translate it to English soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `noSelectionOption="true"` to both dropdowns;

Changed the `prepareEdit` method to:

```
public void prepareEdit(int id) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("estabelecimento_id", id);
    this.estabelecimento = this.estabelecimentoBean.findById(id);
    this.rede = (Rede) this.redeBean.findWithNamedQuery("Rede.findByEstabelecimentoId", map).get(0);
    this.categoria = (CategoriaEstabelecimento) this.categoriaBean.findWithNamedQuery("CategoriaEstabelecimento.findByEstabelecimentoId", map).get(0);
}
```

It's working now.